# Spring MVC controller create file path

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I want to create file path in controller

Already created file path and it's working

```
try {
    Files.write(Paths.get("D:\\app\\app\\java.ini"), data, StandardCharsets.UTF_8, StandardOpenOption.CREATE);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Now i want to change this `D:\\app\\app\\java.ini` and i want to create like `resources/java.ini`

I don't to give any system full path.

Thanx

Answer (score 0):

The sample code below shows the example that you need:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String test = MyClass.class.getProtectionDomain()
            .getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath();
        System.out.println(test);
    }
}
```

Assuming that the method you are running is called MyClass, you can have this snippet inside your Java method:

```
try {
    String location = MyClass.class.getProtectionDomain()
        .getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath() + "resources/java.ini");
    Files.write(location, data, StandardCharsets.UTF_8, StandardOpenOption.CREATE);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: The method write(Path, Iterable<? extends CharSequence>, Charset, OpenOption...) in the type Files is not applicable for the arguments (String, List<String>, Charset, StandardOpenOption)

Comment: My project in D drive , The path you given C drive

Comment: then change the Drive Name.